# How to build an Android home screen widget?

Tags: android, widget

So I'm looking to build a widget that sits on the homescreen  and take up as much of the screen as is possible for a widget to get the most screen space. I have experience building normal apps and already starting building this app as a non-widget. How difficult would it be for me to either re-build or change it into a widget?

Would I be able to use the same basic code from my original app with modifications so that it could function as a widget on the home screen?